# ORIENTDB: traverse / edges with attributes

Tags: orientdb

I have a application permission related question in a graph database. The structure is as follows ... and I have to read the role of a user related to a node. The nodes are hierarchically organized and the roles are provided as Edges containing a type attribute and the relation User -> UserRole {type:xyz} -> Node

```
create class User extends V    
create class Node extends V  
create class has_father extends E
create class UserRole extends E

create vertex User set name = 'u1'
create vertex User set name = 'u2'
create vertex User set name = 'u3'   



create vertex Node set name = 'n1'
create vertex Node set name = 'n11'
create vertex Node set name = 'n12'
create vertex Node set name = 'n111'    
create vertex Node set name = 'n112'
create vertex Node set name = 'n1111'
create vertex Node set name = 'n1112'
create vertex Node set name = 'n11111'
create vertex Node set name = 'n11112'

create edge has_father from (select from Node where name = 'n11') to (select from Node where name = 'n1')
create edge has_father from (select from Node where name = 'n12') to (select from Node where name = 'n1')
create edge has_father from (select from Node where name = 'n111') to (select from Node where name = 'n11')
create edge has_father from (select from Node where name = 'n112') to (select from Node where name = 'n11')
create edge has_father from (select from Node where name = 'n1111') to (select from Node where name = 'n111')
create edge has_father from (select from Node where name = 'n1112') to (select from Node where name = 'n111')
create edge has_father from (select from Node where name = 'n11111') to (select from Node where name = 'n1111')
create edge has_father from (select from Node where name = 'n11112') to (select from Node where name = 'n1111')

create edge UserRole from (select from User where name = 'u1') to (select from Node where name = 'n1') set type = 'admin'
create edge UserRole from (select from User where name = 'u1') to (select from Node where name = 'n11') set type = 'read'
create edge UserRole from (select from User where name = 'u2') to (select from Node where name = 'n111') set type = 'write'
create edge UserRole from (select from User where name = 'u1') to (select from Node where name = 'n11111') set type = 'test'
```

actually i have to read now all children from "n" and get the Node and the UserRole of User "u1":

asking for "u1" and "n1":

```
n11 read
n12 admin
```

asking for "u1" and "n1111":

```
n11111 test
n11112 read
```

Meaning that there is max 1 UserRole assigned and the value might get overridden within the tree. A user might be 
admin for root level and only read from level n11 on.

How can I read the children Nodes passing the father @rid (or a filter) and the calculated Roles for a special User?

Comment: Hello, could be useful for you a javascript or java function?

Comment: Hi Ivan, when there is no good way with straight SQL, then a JS function would be fine ... thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this SQL for your 2nd example:

```sql
select name as Name, $a.type[0] as Role from (select expand(in('has_father')) from (select from Node where name = 'n1111') unwind in)

let $a=(select inE('UserRole').type as type from (
            traverse out('has_father'),in('UserRole') from $parent.$current while out('UserRole').@rid <> #21:0
            ) where in('UserRole').@rid = #21:0
            limit 1
        )
```

where #21:0 is the `u1` @rid.

As long this isn't so much pretty, you could insert this in JS function and parametrise it.

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: Helped a lot! 
I have another simple String property "role" on the Node which I have to return. I can't get it converted to type String as the native one when returned. The derived ones are objects like [{"@type":"d","@rid":"#-2:0","@version":0,"role":"private"}] ?

..., ifnull(role, 
                      (
                       select role from (SELECT expand(out('has_father')) FROM (select from (TRAVERSE out("has_father") FROM #12:1 while role is null)))
                   ) 
                  )  as NodeRole 
from (select expand(in('has_father')) from (select from #12:1) unwind in)

Comment: finally I made it! Many thanks again:

select *, $a.type[0]  as UserRole, ifNull(role, last($b.role))  as NodeRole
from (select expand(in('has_father')) from (select from #12:5) unwind in)

let $a=(select inE('UserRole').type as type from (
            traverse out('has_father'),in('UserRole') from $parent.$current while out('UserRole').@rid <> #14:0
            ) where in('UserRole').@rid = #14:0
            limit 1
        ),
 $b=( SELECT expand(out('has_father')).role FROM (select from (TRAVERSE out("has_father") FROM $parent.$current while role is null)) 
   )